# How to calculate sum of preceeding rows on each row in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query which returns transaction history for a particular user.

`SELECT amount, type, date FROM wallet WHERE user_id = 1 ORDER BY date DESC`

```
amount  type              date           
100.00  debit             2017-05-18 18:46:32  
10.00   debit             2017-05-18 17:51:16   
50.00   debit             2017-05-18 17:44:58  
50.00   debit             2017-05-18 17:44:08  
50.00   credit            2017-05-18 17:42:58  
100.00  credit            2017-05-18 17:42:46  
100.00  credit            2017-05-18 17:42:23
```

I want to add a new column `balance` to the result which shows the balance amount at after that particular transaction. So the above result should look like:

```
amount  type              date                 balance    
100.00  debit             2017-05-18 18:46:32  40.00    
10.00   debit             2017-05-18 17:51:16  140.00  
50.00   debit             2017-05-18 17:44:58  150.00  
50.00   debit             2017-05-18 17:44:08  200.00  
50.00   credit            2017-05-18 17:42:58  250.00    
100.00  credit            2017-05-18 17:42:46  200.00    
100.00  credit            2017-05-18 17:42:23  100.00
```

I can achieve this in PHP. But I am looking for a query which can generate the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this if you allow user variables. I don't know if you want to add it beforehand or afterwards.

*Note that this query is not tested*

```
SET @balance = (SELECT basebalance FROM wallet WHERE user_id=1);

SELECT amount, 
       type, 
       date, 
       @balance as currentbalance, 
       @balance:=IF(type='debit', @balance + amount, @balance - amount) as newbalance 
FROM wallet 
WHERE user_id = 1 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

If you don't allow user variables you have to join the table where w2.ID < w1.currentid. The IFNULL is for the first record which does not have a previous record. Therefor you don't want to get a NULL as response but the first amount.

*Also not tested*

```
 SELECT w1.amount, 
       w1.type, 
       w1.date, 
       w1.amount + IFNULL(SUM(IF(type='credit', w2.amount * -1, w2.amount)), 0) as balance
FROM wallet w1
LEFT JOIN wallet w2 ON w1.user_id=w2.user_id AND w2.id < w1.id
WHERE w1.user_id = 1 
GROUP BY w1.id
ORDER BY w1.date DESC
```